# pandas database merge on multiple columns not merging correctly

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am running into the following issue. I want to merge two dataframes on multiple columns(11 to be exact). Surprisingly the usual methods do not work. Example dataframes are as follows:
df1:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count
1   2   a   ff  0   1   5
1   2   b   fg  1   3   6
1   2   c   hg  2   4   20
1   2   d   gf  0   1   7
1   2   e   fg  1   4   1
```

df2:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  event_type  event_price
1   2   a   ff  0   1   a           20
1   2   b   fg  1   3   a           20
1   2   c   hg  2   4   b           30
1   2   d   gf  0   1   b           40
1   2   e   fg  1   4   b           50
```

I tried

> result =  pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on =
>   ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6'])

and also this should technically work:

> result =  pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer')

But I get this:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count event_type  event_price
1   2   a   ff  0   1   5       
1   2   b   fg  1   3   6       
1   2   c   hg  2   4   20      
1   2   d   gf  0   1   7       
1   2   e   fg  1   4   1       
1   2   a   ff  0   1               a           20
1   2   b   fg  1   3               a           20
1   2   c   hg  2   4               b           30
1   2   d   gf  0   1               b           40
1   2   e   fg  1   4               b           50
```

When I want to get this:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count event_type  event_price
1   2   a   ff  0   1   5            a          20
1   2   b   fg  1   3   6            a          20
1   2   c   hg  2   4   20           b          30
1   2   d   gf  0   1   7            b          40
1   2   e   fg  1   4   1            b          50
```

I also tried with indexes:

> df1_index = df1.set_index(['c1', 'c2','c3'....]); 
>   df2_index =df2.set_index(['c1', 'c2','c3'....]);
>   result = pd.concat([df1_index, df2_index], axis=1);

But that gave the same wrong result. I made sure the dtypes of the two tables are the same as well. I am not sure what else to try. Any advice? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Using your sample data and code this works, are you sure there isn't some other problem

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you describe can happen if the values in one DataFrame are numeric *strings*, while in the other are numerals. They look the same but compare differently.

For example, consider `df1` and `df2` below. Their `c` columns are identical except that `df1['c1']` contains strings, while `df2['c1']` contains ints.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
 'c2': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'c3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 'c4': ['ff', 'fg', 'hg', 'gf', 'fg'],
 'c5': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
 'c6': [1, 3, 4, 1, 4],
 'event_count': [5, 6, 20, 7, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 'c2': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 'c3': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 'c4': ['ff', 'fg', 'hg', 'gf', 'fg'],
 'c5': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
 'c6': [1, 3, 4, 1, 4],
 'event_price': [20, 20, 30, 40, 50],
 'event_type': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']})
```

Merging fails to match any rows because `1 != '1'`:

```
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer'))
#   c1  c2 c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count  event_price event_type
# 0  1   2  a  ff   0   1            5          NaN        NaN
# 1  1   2  b  fg   1   3            6          NaN        NaN
# 2  1   2  c  hg   2   4           20          NaN        NaN
# 3  1   2  d  gf   0   1            7          NaN        NaN
# 4  1   2  e  fg   1   4            1          NaN        NaN
# 5  1   2  a  ff   0   1          NaN           20          a
# 6  1   2  b  fg   1   3          NaN           20          a
# 7  1   2  c  hg   2   4          NaN           30          b
# 8  1   2  d  gf   0   1          NaN           40          b
# 9  1   2  e  fg   1   4          NaN           50          b
```

If we convert the numeric strings to numerals, then merging 
succeeds as expected:

```
df1 = df1.convert_objects(numeric=True)
df2 = df2.convert_objects(numeric=True) # not necessary in my example, but may be necessary for you if the numeric strings are in df2.
print(pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer'))
```

yields

```
   c1  c2 c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count  event_price event_type
0   1   2  a  ff   0   1            5           20          a
1   1   2  b  fg   1   3            6           20          a
2   1   2  c  hg   2   4           20           30          b
3   1   2  d  gf   0   1            7           40          b
4   1   2  e  fg   1   4            1           50          b
```

While `df1 = df1.convert_objects(numeric=True)` may fix your problem, it
would be better to go back and fix the problem at its source, when `df1` and/or
`df2` are first defined.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I also checked and changed all data types in both data frames to the same to make sure this was not the case but I used astype() not convert_objects. I will try with convert_object to see if that works better for me. But you are also right that is it best to fix the problem at the source. This data come from dbb queries and if I just pass the dataframes without doing any modifications they are merged correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing an outer join? As far as I got you need an inner join.
This `df1.merge(df2)` gives me:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  event_count event_type  event_price
0   1   2   a   ff  0   1   5              a            20
1   1   2   b   fg  1   3   6              a            20
2   1   2   c   hg  2   4   20             b            30
3   1   2   d   gf  0   1   7              b            40
4   1   2   e   fg  1   4   1              b            50
```

Comment: Might not be why OP was doing it, but I do 'outer' joins the first several times until I'm sure I'm not doing the join wrong.